# How to put column header without data when export to Excel Syncfusion grid in ASP.NET Core

Tags: excel, grid, syncfusion

I want to put column header without data.

If I have grid like this, I want to print with out Item Code's data:

[image]

like this Excel:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing your query, we could see that you like to export the column without data. You can achieve your requirement by using the excelQueryCellInfo event of Grid. Please refer the below code example and API for more information.

[image]

API: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/api/grid/#excelquerycellinfo

Screenshot:

[image]
[image]

Comment: In my project I just hide it T0T. thanks for your answer!